# How can I include debug information with nasm?

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, nasm

I have this source code:

```
;  hello.asm  a first program for nasm for Linux, Intel, gcc
;
; assemble: nasm -f elf -l hello.lst  hello.asm
; link:     gcc -o hello  hello.o
; run:          hello 
; output is:    Hello World 

    SECTION .data       ; data section
msg:    db "Hello World",10 ; the string to print, 10=cr
len:    equ $-msg       ; "$" means "here"
                ; len is a value, not an address

    SECTION .text       ; code section
        global main     ; make label available to linker 
main:               ; standard  gcc  entry point

    mov edx,len     ; arg3, length of string to print
    mov ecx,msg     ; arg2, pointer to string
    mov ebx,1       ; arg1, where to write, screen
    mov eax,4       ; write command to int 80 hex
    int 0x80        ; interrupt 80 hex, call kernel

    mov ebx,0       ; exit code, 0=normal
    mov eax,1       ; exit command to kernel
    int 0x80        ; interrupt 80 hex, call kernel
```

This code is taken from [here](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/undergraduate/313/spring05/burt_katz/lectures/Lect02/helloasm.html).

I am running **ubuntu 12.04 32-bit** on VirtualBox for learning purposes.

Steps I follow are:

- nasm -f elf -g -F stabs hello.asm
- ld -o hello hello.o
- gdb hello -tui

Now when I only run **hello** it will run fine but gdb fails to show any source code. Why? When I tryp **run** in gdb I will see **Hello World** text just fine but it does not show the source.

Comment: That's a bug somewhere in nasm or gdb. Note that if you start doing `si` for example, `gdb` will happily show you the source code.

Comment: what do you mean "start doing si" @Jester ?

Comment: Use the `si` command to single step instructions. `gdb` will correctly show the source code. Use `start` instead of `run` or place a breakpoint manually first.

Comment: @Jester Sorry, can you give a full example as an answer? I am very new to Assembly and I have no idea what "use the si command to single step instructions" mean.. Sorry :)

Comment: Excellent commenting style.  Voted +1 for that factor alone

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like stabs format doesn't work with GDB, try DWARF instead ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF )

compile with

> nasm -f elf -g -F dwarf hello.asm

then in gdb type

> start

then

> si

you will see sources with comments so on. as Koray Tugay said there is most probably a bug in gdb.

Comment: May also help to put `nop` as the first instruction after... well, you're using `main`. Does `ld` not complain about the lack of an entrypoint? `ld` usually expects `_start` - `gcc` (like it says where you found the code) expects `main`. Tell `ld` `-e main` or change it to `_start` to shut `ld` up... or use `gcc`...

Comment: @FrankKotler Thanks for the information. _start made ld not complain anymore. But what is the cause for this? Any source I can read?

Comment: Some tutorials here: http://asm.sourceforge.net/resources.html#tutorials You might find that kind of information in the "teensy" tutorial, although writing obsessively short files is probably not something you want to do. Of course there's `man ld`...