# layout next shows [ No Source Available ]

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I can't understand why 'layout next' has stopped showing code. It worked for some time and i was happy with 'layout next' option but now i constantly see the error. Awkwardly enough i could find only one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027651/gdb-complains-no-source-available) relating that topic which doesn't seem to solve the problem. Any ideas how to bring this function back?

Maybe i should find some compilation flag to enable this?

```
EDIT:
```

Make sure you add -g flag on compilation and type run after 'layout next' window have appeared.

Comment: Don't comment your own question for no reaseon, instead [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No Source Available

The error means literally that: GDB doesn't know where the source for the current program location is.

There are several possible reasons:

- you have not started the program yet
- you built your program without debugging info (without `-g` flag)
- you are stopped inside a system library
- you moved the source to a different location after the program was built

Answer (score 0):

"you moved the source to a different location after the program was built",this works for me, thank you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34652810)